# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass, while accessing attribute 'name' in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have linked `user` and `role` table.
I want to access the name attribute of role table in user controller. I have used `<td><%= user.Role.name %></td>`.

I get `undefined method 'name' error`.

Comment: Show your association between User and Role models

Comment: In user model    belongs_to :Role, class_name: "Role", foreign_key: :role_id

Comment: Did not you try by replacing `R` with `r` in your code?

Comment: btw, yes, you should not use `Capital` case for method names, use `belongs_to :role`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from `user.role` being null. This can happen at any time, especially if the foreign key is in the roles table.

You need to protect yourself against it by using (depending on ruby version and willingness of putting more architecture in your code) either:

1. Safe navigation (from ruby 2.3 onwards)

   ```
   <td><%= user.role&.name %></td>
   ```
2. Rails-style safe method call

   ```
   <td><%= user.role.try(&:name) %></td>
   ```
3. Wrapper method in User model

   ```
   class User < ...
     def role_name
       role.name if role
       # or role&.name
     end

     # equivalently, this defines a safe `role_name` method.
     delegate :name, to: :role, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
   end

   <td><%= @user.role_name %></td>
   ```
4. Decorator

   ```
   class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator # for instance
     decorates :user

     delegate_all
     delegate :name, to: :role, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
   end

   class YourController < ...
     def show
       ...
       @user = UserDecorator.new(user)
     end
   end

   <td><%= @user.role_name %></td>
   ```

The advantage of the last option is that you get a nice interface in your view, but at the same point you don't get your model messed up with view-related code.

Comment: `user.role&.name` is good choice for ruby upper version instead of using `try`

Comment: @ray nice catch and in this case appropriate. Although safe navigation (`&.`) and `ActiveSupport::Tryable#try` are not the same thing and react very differently depending on the circumstances.[AS#try vs Safe Navigation](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/AStry-vs-and-Safe-Navigation)

Comment: @engineersmnky I did not know this so deep! Thanks for the brief info :) You nailed it with specs written!

Comment: @engineersmnky `.try` with block behaves as expected. See updated specs here (context '#try with block') https://repl.it/@SaverioTrioni/HopefulSneakyYottabyte-1

Comment: @rewritten lines 73-91 have no bearing on the spec since they are incorrect. line 78 shows `obj` should not receive `&` which of course it wont becuase the only `&` is `Symbol#to_proc` short hand and I have already shown that `try` will yield self to the block when the arity != 0. Test on line 84 only proves that `NilClass#try` returns `nil` without evaluation as proven in both `try` and `try!` specs. Safe Navigation is a construct; `try` is a method call. The only update I can agree with in this case is that `try` with a block does not handle `NoMethodError` (mostly because it uses `try!`)

Comment: Also line 74 is very misleading since you are not calling `try` with a method name; instead you are calling try with a `Proc` formed from a symbol that is implied to be a method name. e.g. `try(:name)` is how the rest of the spec defines "with a method name" and this is not the same as `try(&:name)` which is a kin to `try { |a| a.name } `

Comment: I agree that they are not the same, I just took your specs for `&.` and converted them to `.try(&blk)`. And of course they are not the same under the hood. But they exhibit the same exact behavior, which is what I was conveying in the original response. Actually I _never_ use `try` with explicit argument exactly because its behavior with argument is very weird.

Comment: The important parts of try-with-block are: 1. it doesn't handle NoMethodError and 2. it completely skips any treatment of nil. The only big difference with &. (other that one is native) is that .try(&blk) won't work on BasicObject. But then if you use BasicObject, you don't need to read all these responses and comments.

Comment: @rewritten I have updated my spec to include your observation about the block variety of `try`/`try!`

Answer (score -1):

If your model has `has_one: :role` relationship with role then,
`user.role.name` will return name of role

Comment: You should ask OP for data like schema and associations. Presumptions are not expected which will lead increasing numbers of such low quality questions on SO with lack of explanations.

Comment: in user model its  belongs_to :Role, class_name: "Role", foreign_key: :role_id

Comment: i have used select form  <%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ :include_blank => "Please select" }, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>. I need to display the name attribute .how can i display that?

Comment: @Sneha User model should have `belongs_to :role` only, as class_name & foreign_key are evaluated as what you were providing by convention.